# When does string session expires?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I made an app that counts active members of my telegram channel using Telethon(telegram api library). my app gets the active rate per hour via api and writes it into a google spreads sheet.
I had to use 'String session' so I would not have to log in more than once, and keep the app running every day.
However, I'm not really sure when this string session thing expires. The official document does not say anything about it.

I read on a website 'Treat the session file/string, your API ID and hash as your password. Anyone got on hold of these 3 will be able to gain full access to your Telegram account until you revoke it.' so If it is until I revoke it, I assume it lasts forever?

It would be great if anyone could tell me when it expires.

Answer (score 4):

`StringSession` is just like any other session, it won't expire unless revoke the session.